Is the measure of the cut locus of a Riemannian manifold zero?
For an arbitrary Riemannian manifold $M$ and $E\subseteq M$, we can define the exterior measure as $$\mu_{*}(E) = \inf\{\mathrm{Vol}(U)\mid U \text{ is open and } E\subseteq U\}.$$ This can induce a measure $\mu$ on the $\sigma$-algebra of Carathéodory measurable sets.
Suppose $M$ is a Riemannian manifold which satisfies that every two points can be joined by a minimizing geodesic. For any $p\in M$, is the exterior measure of the cut locus $\mathrm{Cut}(p)$ of $p$ zero? If so, we can deduce that $\mathrm{Cut}(p)$ is measurable and has measure zero.

The cut locus is closed and hence measurable. Its measure is always zero. See this for instance
